# Spoj ABCD Wrong Answer

Tags: c

Yesterday I was Solving the Spoj problem ABCD: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABCD/

I'm getting Wrong Answer but I really can't figure out why. I've tried all the test cases in forums and comments. Is any valid solution accepted or the only the one they have on their file.

LOGIC:

1. Count the occurrences of each character in row1.
2. Fill row2 one by one checking the upper character the left character and also count < N.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;
int main()
{
  int n;
  int counts[4] = {0};
  char row1[1000000], row2[1000000];
  scanf("%d", &n);
  scanf("%s", row1);

  while(row1[i])
  {
     counts[row1[i] - 'A']++;
     i++;
  }

  i = 0;
  if(counts[0] < n && row1[i] != 'A')
  {
     row2[i] = 'A';
     counts[0]++;
  }
  else if(counts[1] < n && row1[i] != 'B')
  {
     row2[i] = 'B';
     counts[1]++;
  }
  else if(counts[2] < n && row1[i] != 'C')
  {
    row2[i] = 'C';
    counts[2]++;
  }
  else
  {
     row2[i] = 'D';
     counts[3]++;
  }
  i++;
  while(i < (2 * n))
  {
    if(counts[0] < n && row1[i] != 'A' && row2[i - 1] != 'A')
    {
      row2[i] = 'A';
      counts[0]++;
    }
    else if(counts[1] < n && row1[i] != 'B' && row2[i - 1] != 'B')
    {
       row2[i] = 'B';
       counts[1]++;
    }
    else if(counts[2] < n && row1[i] != 'C' && row2[i - 1] != 'C')
    {
       row2[i] = 'C';
       counts[2]++;
    }
    else
    {
       row2[i] = 'D';
       counts[3]++;
    }

    i++;
 }
 row2[i] = '\0';
 printf("%s", row2);
 return 0;
 }
```

I've Been Debugging For Hours without Knowing what to debug.
Even SPOJ forum didn't find me a solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugger. Especially not for school contests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i did pretty much the same thing and got WA too :P Here's the problem with this logic .

Try this testcase
3
ABACAD

Output can be:
BCDBDC